# Exec procedure with @tpv from Sql

Tags: sql, procedure

I want to exec my procedure from sql, but I don't know how.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ListCrc32] AS TABLE(
    [crc32] [int] NULL
)
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[UpdateAdsList]
@tvp ListCrc32 readonly
as
 update tb
 set a_update=CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),101)
 from Ads tb
 join @tvp t on t.crc32 = a_crc32
```

I want to exec the proc from sql, but I don't know how to create an object type of UpdateAdsList, and send it to the procedure to - @tvp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy ..

```
declare @ ListCrc32

insert into @ (crc32)
select ... put here what you need to insert with.

exec UpdateAdsList @
```

Or not to create confusion, you can declare @varname and insert into it and call with it.